# What web dev oriented SDK is suitable for Chromebook?

Tags: web-development, chromebook

I am wondering if I could run something like WebStorm or Sublime Text on chromebook. What else would I miss on Chromebook that I normally use? FTP client? NodeJS server?

Comment: Have you used [Cloud 9 IDE](https://c9.io/)?

Comment: It looks very good, I am going to have a better look. Please make this a real answer so that I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of IDE's suitable for Chromebook:
- sourceLair 
- CloudIDE 
- Shift Edit 
- Cloud9
- Codeanywhere

I have a too low reputation to give You a link to each of them, so here is two articles to help You choose:
http://www.chromebookhq.com/five-best-online-ides-making-the-switch-to-a-chromebook/
http://www.slant.co/topics/713/~what-is-the-best-cloud-ide

Hope it helps !

Comment: I am going to check them out - do you happen to know if any of them support TypeScript?

Comment: Cloud9 is supporting Typescrypt